# Get database schema when getting the table metadata

Tags: c#, sql-server

*Please note that when I using the word "schema" I mean Schema as the security feature provided by Sql Server ("dbo"...) that you must provide with the table name if you want your query to succeed, NOT its metadata (columns...).*

I'm using this bit of code to get the table metadata (columns, types, etc) :

```
// Parameter table includes the schema name.
public DataTable GetTableSchema(string table)
{
    var tbl = new DataTable();
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE 1=0", table), conn))
    {
        tbl = adapter.FillSchema(tbl, SchemaType.Source);
    }    
    return tbl;
}
```

My issue is that the property `DataTable.TableName` doesn't contain the table schema ("dbo", or any custom schema) and I can't find any property in the object that allows me to get that information, so it is lost during the process (or I have to pass several variables to methods, while I'd like to keep everything in the DataTable object, which should be logical).
Where / how can I get it along with the database structure ?

Only solution I found : adding `tbl.TableName = table;` before returning the table but it feels... wrong.

Comment: Be aware that you can have two tables with the exact same name in different Schemas.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't mention that the "table" parameter includes the schema and the table name.

Answer (score 3):

You could query the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx).TABLES view and get your info from the TABLE_SCHEMA field

```
 "SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_name = '" + table "'";
```

It is not clear why you need this info, so I can only suggest to run this code

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA 
                                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@table", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = table;
string schema = (string)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

There is also an alternative, that could return some of the info on your table and the table_schema in a single call

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = cnn.GetSchema("COLUMNS", new string[] { null, null, table, null });
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[0]["TABLE_SCHEMA"].ToString());
```

This code returns a lot of info about your table and also the TABLE_SCHEMA colum.
Not sure if this approach is suitable for your purpose because here the datatable returned contains a row for each column and each column of this DataTable contains details about the columns (Like OrdinalPosition, IsNullable, DataType, Character_Maximum_Length)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was hoping that FillSchema, which give me A LOT of details about the table would provide the schema information, which is quite important :). 
I need it because I build custom queries (to perform checks, inserts or updates) so need to manipulate the table name along with the schema, or none of the queries would work.
I obviously already have it (as I can call FillSchema), but it's not in the DataTable object, I need to pass it with another parameter, it doesn't feel right.

Comment: There is an alternative, just tried it, addin to the answer now

Comment: Thanks ! I'm not a fan of data returned as an array instead of a proper object, but it does the job.